# What is is minimum possible number for an ECDSA private key?

Tags: ecdsa

Private keys are 256 bit numbers. I know the max. possible number is something around:
115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336

What about the min. number possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The all-zero bitstring doesn't have a corresponding public key per the standard (according to ["Are all possible EC private keys valid?" on Crypto.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30272/8801)), so it's `000…001`.

Answer (score 8):

One is the minimum number. [This space intentionally left unblank.]

Comment: "♫ One... is... the minimum number for a private key... ♫"

Comment: If only I'd thought of that to get around the minimum answer length. :)